# this.property returns undefined in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I'm writing an app in node and I am running into something strange.

I pass an object into a function with the call() method to modify that object. When inside the function when I do console.log(this) it returns the object fine, however when I try to do console.log(this.foo) or try to modify the object it says undefined. **UPDATE:** I also have to mention I pass this function in an object because I have to inject the functions in to another function. (more specific, I'm trying to get [this](https://github.com/InterNACHI/mongoose-data-migrations) to work. Maybe that is also part of the problem.

```
var obj = {name: "John", age: 23};
var functions = {up: function() { /* do stuff */ }, down: function() { /* do stuff */
functions.up.call(obj);

up: function() {
    console.log(this); //returns {name: "John", age: 23}
    console.log(this.name); //returns undefined
    this.wife = "Jenny"; //doesn't do anything
}
```

However if I set properties with an '_' they do exist but don't show up when I call console.log(this);

```
up: function() {
    this._wife = "Jenny"; //doesn't do anything
    console.log(this._wife); //returns "Jenny"
    console.log(this); //still returns {name: "John", age: 23}
}
```

I've tried everything like using this.set(key, value), this.get(key), this.attributes["name"].value,..

Maybe I'm misunderstanding how 'this' works, but after hours of searching and trying things I'm clueless..

Answer (score 2):

When trying your code in the console I fixed the syntax to a function expression and it works for me, perhaps this was your problem?

```
var obj = {name: "John", age: 23};
up.call(obj);

function up() {
    console.log(this); //returns {name: "John", age: 23}
    console.log(this.name); //returns "John"
    this.wife = "Jenny"; // works
    console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Ronny, however I can't really do that since I have to pass the function via an object (should have mentioned that perhaps). I've updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting working output from this in node, chrome/win7 & notepad++ plugin :

```
var obj = { name: "John", age: 23 };
var functions = {
  up: function() {
      console.log(this); //returns {name: "John", age: 23}
      console.log(this.name); //returns undefined
      this.wife = "Jenny"; }, //doesn't do anything
  down: function(){ } }
functions.up.call(obj);
console.log('obj:',obj);
```

output :

> { name: 'John', age: 23 }
>   John
>   obj: { name: 'John', age: 23, wife: 'Jenny' }

Your understanding of 'this' seems correct
you could try replacing

```
functions.up.call(obj);
```

with

```
temp = obj.up;
obj.up = functions.up;
obj.up();
obj.up = temp;//or: delete obj.up;
```

Comment: could it be related to the version of node.exe? i've got file version:0.10.25.0, product version:0.10.25

Comment: I'm running the same Node version, so that's not the problem. Also you're code alone works fine, however when using it together with the npm module I mentioned above https://github.com/InterNACHI/mongoose-data-migrations it has the same problem so it must be something with the module however I can't find anything wrong with it.. Still clueless.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Finally I found solution - I put the problematic code in round brackets:

```
var i = node.declarations.length; //Error: cannot get length of undefined
var i = (node.declarations).length; // 11
```

I guess you should do something like that:

```
console.log((this.name).toString());
```

or

```
console.log((this.name));
```